# Can't install a package. The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, postgresql

I am trying to install php5-pgsql:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

but I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-pgsql :     
Depends: phpapi-20121212     
Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21) but 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed    
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried every solution i found but it won't work!

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I tried it already. It doesn't work.. i get this: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Ok try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+`deprecated+dontuse`+deb.sury.org~trusty+1